# Custom table style not saved in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013, styles

I have created a custom table style based on the normal table style, which I named "Table 1".

I then created a table in the document, applied the style (correctly), and saved the document.

Before closing it, I selected the table, and in the "design" TAB it correctly showed the style I had selected; however, after closing and reopening the file, the style is still "applied" but not selected in the "design" TAB, so if I change the custom style the table does not reflect it and I have to re-apply it.

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I created a simple test case [on dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h68xpkdcnrgtc3w/target2.doc?dl=0), in which the table should be linked to a style named "Tabella 1" which is present on the document; if I re-open the file however the link with the style is lost.

Comment: if the style not selected, is it still there in the style gallery (not deleted)?

Comment: Yes, it is present in the gallery, and it was shown as selected before closing and re-opening the file.

Comment: if your document is long, or the table itself is long, then this problem is likely to happen that no style was applied to your table. Kindly share a sample of your document with the table in question so anyone can see it :)

Comment: @Sanny see link to test case in the question itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the sample file you attached, I noticed that you are using the old 97-2003 `.doc` file format. While table styles were introduced in 2003, the then new feature couldn't work well as in nowadays; so I wouldn't be surprised that the old file format caused such an issue in the 2016 edition. Converting the same file to the newer `.docx` format solved the problem.

Besides memorising the table's style, you can update all tables automatically once you modify their styles. If the file is a `.doc`, the modifications will apply only on the table which has the cursor in.

Comment: @MatteoTassinari You're welcome! If this post solved your problem, mark it as the answer to let other people know.